# What is it called when a input method recognizes programming keywords and structures?

Tags: ide, editor

For some reason the term lexer or parser comes mind.  I realise these terms are often associated with compilers, but I don't want to make any assumptions.   For example, when you open .cpp file in gedit, it colors string literals, numeric values, data types, etc all different colors to make it a bit more readable.  The same goes with SO and visual studio.  What's the **term** for what these programs are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Syntax highlighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting).  From Wikipedia:

> Syntax highlighting is a feature of some text editors that display
>   text—especially source code—in different colors and fonts according to
>   the category of terms. This feature eases writing in a structured
>   language such as a programming language or a markup language as both
>   structures and syntax errors are visually distinct. Highlighting does
>   not affect the meaning of the text itself; it's made only for human
>   readers/editors.

Answer (score 1):

It is called ["syntax highlighting"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting).